# The conflict between angular directive selector and tslint

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, tslint

I am using angular 4 directive to define an angular attribute directive.
But I want to use this directive as a class. My definition is (It works fine) :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.input-field'
})
```

This is according to angular selector definition (the **.class** one)

[image]

But I got a tslint error as below:

[image: tslint error]

Is there any way to fix this error without disable the tslint rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same error and opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26490). This is the answer I got:

> While Angular does support class selectors for directives, this feature should be used only in special circumstances because it makes it hard to understand which parts of the template are regular classes and which are directives. This is why this syntax is tslint warning and not a compilation error.
>
> If you insist on using this selector style, you can change the tslint config, or prefix the callsite in the code with tslint ignore comment, but you'll make your life and other's life easier if you stick to attribute selectors instead.

This is not very satisfying, but there seems no way around it.

Answer (score 4):

To have multiple prefixes validated in the same project, you can just use the following (in `tslint.json` file):

```
...
"component-selector": [true, "element", ["app", "my-awsome-prefix", "another-prefix"], "kebab-case"],
...
```

And same for the Directives:

```
...
"directive-selector": [true, "attribute", ["app", "myDirectivePrefix"], "camelCase"],
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't work for me. The issue is there are `element`, `attribute` in `directive-selector`, but no `class`. I still can't figure it out

Answer (score 3):

In this case your rule prevents you from using class selectors so you have to disable it. The question is to disable it globally or not?

You can disable a specific rule in a block of code like that:

```
/* tslint:disable: no-use-before-declare */

some code breaking no-use-before-declare rule

/* tslint:enable: no-use-before-declare */
```

Or you can disable entire tslint for the next line

```
// tslint:disable-next-line
some code breaking all the rules
normal code
```

Comment: I want to ask is there a better solution with disable the tslint rule? Or is there any issue with the name I defined

Comment: @EmonZan What your directive-selector property is set to in tslintconfig? If it's set to attribute then you can't do much about it if you want a class. And this rule accepts only "element" or "attribute" (forces components either to be elements or attributes). http://codelyzer.com/rules/directive-selector

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy Malyutin, This is my directive-selector: `"directive-selector":[true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"]`, Thank you!

Comment: i think case need suitable solution, not disable lint and go

Comment: Thanks was useful to disable the linting in this situation

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the following array typing:

```
public dateFormats: Array<{ format: string, eq: string }> = [...];
```

Not using the *generic syntax* fixed the errors.

I will definitely consider migrating from `tslint` to `eslint` as the support is discontinued when it comes to Angular CLI.